# Xcodeでビルドすると画像の色が変わってしまいます

Tags: xcode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]プログラミングとは別の話になってしまうのかもしれませんが、Xcode10でXcodeのシミュレーター,実機テストどちらも、用意した画像の色が変わってしまいます。
例えばブロックくずしだと赤色のボールが青色に変わってしまいます。
Xcode上で組み込まれた画像ファイルを見る時は画像の色は問題ないですが、ビルドすると赤が青、ピンクが青紫になってしまいます。
何か心当たりある方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
(どうやらRGBがBGRになっているようです)

Comment: プロジェクトに追加したファイルの画像フォーマットは何でしょうか？また、シミュレーターの画面、実機での画面、それぞれでスクリーンショットを取ると、スクリーンショットの色は見えている色・元ファイルの色どちらになるのか。もう一つ、写真の様な単色でない画像を表示させても色味がシフトするのでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。スクリーンショットの方載せます。pngです。写真でも色変わるようです。スクリーンショットは元ファイルの色になります。

Comment: pngファイルにICCプロファイルが含まれていないのが原因でないでしょうか？ColorSyncなんかに使われている「この色はどんな環境でこの色に見えているものですよ」っていう情報です。有償ソフトですが、GraphicConverterなんかがICCプロファイル付きのpngの書き出しに対応しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみにXcodeに画像の色を変えるような設定ってあるのでしょうか？

Comment: ごめんなさい。なにを聞きたいのかがコメントから読み取れません

Comment: RGBがBGRになってしまう原因のプログラムがあるのか？みたいなニュアンスの質問になってしまうのですが。

Comment: RGBの各色が同じでもモニターの特性で色が違って見えることがあり、それを補正して同じ見た目にするための補正データーがICCプロファイルというデーターです。このデーターがpngファイルに含まれていないため、シミュレーターやiPhoneで色が変わって見えるのではないか？と想像しています。なので、Mac=Xcodeで見える色とシミュレーター＝iPhoneで見える色が違っているのではないでしょうか。つまり、色を変えるコードがあるのではなく、色を揃えるデーターがないのではいか？ということです。これで答えになっていますか？